# ArcMap 10.4 Find the size of a service area?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.4, service-area

I have a service area for two fire stations, and I'm trying to find out the size of the service areas. But for the life of me, I can't find how to get that information.

Comment: Aren't the service areas polygons?  Have you tried [calculating area](http://52.73.197.188:3344/webappbuilder/apps/44/)?

Comment: If calculating area doesn't solve what you are asking, it would be helpful for you to expand on your question so we understand what you are asking.